# Getting error messages from a Plot expression containing an integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

This should be a really simple question, but I just got confused.

```
Plot[Integrate[x, x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -4.9998. >>
>   Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -4.79571. >>
>   Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -4.59163. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Integrate::ilim will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

And it gives no graph of the function.

At first I was trying to plot a function that *Mathematica* is unable to integrate, but the problem exists with even simple functions.

By the way, *Mathematica* refuses to integrate Log[Abs[x]] while Wolfram|Alpha is able to give the result.

I apologize in advance if this is my stupid mistake.

Comment: `Plot[Integrate[x, x] /. x -> u, {u, -5, 5}]`. You can't Integrate on a variable that has been assigned a value.

Comment: @belisarius so you mean that Mathematica evaluates Plot first and assigns values to x. I thought it evaluates Integrate first. Thanks. by the way, where can I know about the priority of the functions being evaluated?

Comment: Compare with `Plot[Evaluate@Integrate[x, x], {x, -5, 5}]`

Comment: To closers: I would rather prefer to close this one as a dup and not as a "trivial" question. But I can't find any other question covering this _specifically_

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I came across this question today, and I realized at that time I wasn't aware of the `HoldAll` attributes of `Plot`.