# Getting Integrate::ilim error while plotting

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I am a beginner in Mathematica. I want to plot for

```
t = 5

f[x_] = Integrate[Sqrt[ Tanh[x]], x]

r[x_] = Integrate[Cos[f[x]], x]

Plot[r[x], {x, -t, t}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "y", 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 500]
```

but I'm getting error messages:

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -4.99998. >>
>   Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -4.97994. >>
>   Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in -4.9599. >>

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: 1) You should do `Clear[x]` before this code. 2) A more general tip is to learn the difference between `=` and `:=`, especially for function definitions like `f` and `r`. 3) And finally, the RHS of `r[x]` is asking _Mathematica_ to compute an antiderivative for `Cos[-ArcTan[Sqrt[Tanh[x]]] - 1/2 Log[1 - Sqrt[Tanh[x]]] + 
 1/2 Log[1 + Sqrt[Tanh[x]]]` (which is what I get for `Cos[f[x]]`), and this is probably too much to ask. So look into `NIntegrate` instead.

Comment: Related: [(75786)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75786), [(124706)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124706), [(135855)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135855)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had looked at the output of

```
r[x_] = Integrate[Cos[f[x]], x]
```

you would have seen that Mathematica returned the integral unevaluated because it couldn't find a closed-form solution. One way to proceed with solving your problem is to numerically integrate to make a table of points along `r[x]` in the interval of interest.

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Sqrt[Tanh[x]], x]
With[{t = 5., dt = .05},
  data = Table[{u, NIntegrate[Cos[f[x]], {x, -t, u}]}, {u, -t, t, dt}];
  ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]]
```

[image: plot]